# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' in IntelliJ web application

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to build a small web application using servlets on IntelliJ. I am trying to connect MySQL DB with the application using JDBC.

I have the required maven dependencies, checked my context.xml file.
I manually tried connecting the MySQL DB using the GUI on IntelliJ which is getting connected successfully.

[image: The project artifacts]

```
<Context>

<Resource name="jdbc/student_tracker"
          auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
          username="webstudent" password="webstudent"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker"/>
</Context>
```

Here is the Servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", value = "/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Define datasource/connection pool for Resource Injection
    @Resource(name="jdbc/student_tracker")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Step 1:  Set up the printwriter
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        // Step 2:  Get a connection to the database
        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try {
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            // Step 3:  Create a SQL statements
            String sql = "select * from student";
            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            // Step 4:  Execute SQL query
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

            // Step 5:  Process the result set
            while (myRs.next()) {
                String email = myRs.getString("email");
                out.println(email);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:472)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:744)
    at com.application.student_tracker.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:59)
```

Comment: Seems like your context file wasn't deployed to Tomcat. How did you add it to your project and where is it located?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JNDI for DataSource you have to have the JDBC driver in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib.`, copy the `mysql-connector` to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`

Also remove it from your `WEB-INF/lib`

REF: [JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)